# Dokku - check if app running else restart

Tags: dokku

I've deployed my node.js webapp on Dokku, however I've noticed at times the site went down.

I'm investigating why however is there somehow I can run a curl every say 1 hour and if the status isn't 400 do something like `dokku scale 0` then `dokku scale 1` or restart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron with an shell script :

/home/user/script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/curl example.com -s -f -o /dev/null || /usr/bin/dokku ps:restart example_app
```

Curl: -s flag (silent), -f flag (fail with exit code on error) and -o flag to redirect output.

```
chmod +x script.sh (to make it executable)
```

Launch `crontab -e` and paste this

```
0 * * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

It will make repeat the script every hours. (don't forget to remove it the same way when not needed anymore)

[Generate custom crontab](https://crontab.guru/)